# how to use nodejs modules in nw/react app

Tags: reactjs, nwjs

I'm trying to build an app with NW ans react and i'm having  trouble calling node js modules fron react like the "fs" module i got the following error: **TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function**

this is my folders structure:

public
-----files generated by CRA
src
-----main.js
-----handlers.js
-----files generated by CRA

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "nw-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./public/main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "nw" : "nw ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "nw": "^0.64.1"
  }
}
```

main.js

```js
nw.Window.open("http://localhost:3000", {}, function (win) {});
```

handlers.js

```js
const fs = require("fs");

exports.getFiles = cb => {
  const dir = "C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents";
  fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
    cb(files);
  });
};
```

App.js

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

const handlers = require("./handler");

function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    handlers.getFiles(files => {
      setFiles(files);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {files.map(file => (
        <h1 key={file}>{file}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `package.json`:

```json
  "node-remote": [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "file://*"
  ]
```

You may also need this:

```json
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "globals": {
      "nw": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: it works after making this changes and adding  "node-main": "./src/main.js" to package.json and using nw.require() instead of just require but the issue the app is startting twice (2 instances)

Comment: it works great after setting "node-main" to empty  file, if you can explain this i will be grateful

Comment: whent "node-main" is not set require a nodejs module works inside App.js but require script not working without "node-main"

Comment: you really should not be requiring a Node.js script inside a React application. If you need to use CJS modules you should be separating your UI logic from everything else. This can be done with `node-main` or by having `main` set to a script that uses `ns.Window.open()` to display your React app.

Comment: what I'm supposed  to do if i want to access a database and display the result i need to create a service and call it in react app.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use fs module in browser.. it is node core module.

Comment: how to get the the list of files and display the result ?

Comment: https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/

Comment: the way i know is to make a api req to a server and return files from there.. In your server you can use fs too

Comment: this is not a web app this is a desktop app and what i need is the way to connect react with Node-Webkit and node, i know how to do it with electron using IPC.